# fstab not used in kubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: fstab

It's sounds rediculious but I fonud that kubuntu 12.04 doesn't use fstab anymore.
Ti assure you I suggest to perform an experiment:

1. press "Alt+F1" > "System Settings" > "Removable Devices". There you shoud enable automatic mounting of removable media (choose any partition you like).
2. restart you computer
3. open: "/media" folder with "dolphin" to ensure that the selected partition has been mounted.
4. now look in to your "fstab" file

Could anybody explain why there is no record in fstab while partition is mounted automaticaly?

Answer (score 0):

You are partially right: Automatically mounted partitions do not show up in `fstab`.

However, that proves nothing about manually created fstab entries being ignored by the system.
Why do you assume that ALL mounted partitions have to show up in fstab?

Even with the command line `mount`, it is easily possible to mount partitions that do not show up in `fstab` by manually specifying the device, file system and mount point.

For example, try:

```
mkdir foo
sudo mount -t tmpfs none foo
```

That creates a temporary RAM disk and mounts it to the newly created directory foo - without modifying `fstab` or in fact any persistent configuration file.
Instead of tmpfs, you might as well use vfat and a physical device.

Basically, the automatic mounting function you described does just that as soon as it discovers a newly attached disk.